# How to get a :before element open-quote to be inline with div

Tags: html, css

I am using the `:before` element to output an open and closed quotation. An issue I am running into is the amount of white-space around the open quote. I am unsure if the `display` element or the `line-height` is causing this...or possible neither of those.

I set the display to inline thinking that would help. I also set the line-height for the open quote to `0%`.

Does anyone know how I can get the open-quotation to be directly inline with the `testimonial` element? Even if the quotation overlaps some with the content, that would be fine.

```css
#testimonial:before {
 content: open-quote;
 display: inline;
 color: #000;
 font-size: 10rem;
 z-index: -1;
 margin-right: 25px;
 line-height: 0%;
}
#testimonial:after {
 content: close-quote;
 display: inline-block;
 color: #000;
 font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="hG" id="testimonialTitle">Customer Testimonial</h3>
<p class="dGw" id="testimonial">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can't. It's a glyph where the actual "mark" is at the top of the font-space. Try putting a border around it to see. Absolute positioning might be an option.

Comment: Use appropriate tags. The take type should probably be a span, consider also using specific tags quote or block quote tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#testimonial{
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
#testimonial:before {
    content: open-quote;
    display: inline;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 30px;
    z-index: -1;
    margin-right: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 0;
}
#testimonial:after{
    content: close-quote;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

Set testimonial element to be position relative. Place open and close quote using absolute positioning.

Comment: thanks for accepting my answer, If you wish to read, you can send some time at my blog www.creativetechnocrayts.blogspot.com